# Access cookie in Blazor page in sync mode

Tags: c#, blazor, session-cookies, blazor-server-side, .net-7.0

I'm building a web app using .net 7.0 and Blazor.

---

**Step back - basic requirement**

After a couple of hints and tips, I asume, that I'm choosen the wrong way to achive my requirements.

Therefore I want to explain a little more details about the basic situation and requirement - maybe this helps a little to clarify.

The overall connection to data source is managed by instances of `IMoxClientConnection`.
As these objects contains the authentication information of the user, there needs to be a new instance for every user accessing the web page (but not just "scoped" as the user should not have to login on every page he opens).

So I implemented a `ConnectionHandler` which basicaly is a Dictionary of the MoxSessionId and the corresponding `IMoxClientConnection` instance.
*(Which internaly checks if its already present or a new one needs to be created)*
This `ConnectionHandler` is added as a SingletonService so it persists along application runtime.

All the services requires such a `IMoxClientConnection` to access the data source.

The `ConnectionHandler` provides a function `GetClientConnectorForSession(string moxSessionId)` for the services to retrieve the correct `IMoxClientConnection` to use.

Maybe this explaination helps a littel to understand the main idea behind.

---

**Requirement**

I need to get any kind of session id for every client accessing the web app. This session id needs to be persistent as long as the browser tab is open and in use. At the moment it doesn't matter if the data persists when the browser/the tab is closed or not.

**Idea/Tried so far**

My basic idea was to store my own session id (as a string) in a cookie or similar.
As far as I found out this is not that easy in Blazor anymore as it was on "old" asp.net.

I need to access this session id from within my base-service class.
So I tried to use SessionStorage.

I added
`builder.Services.AddScoped<ProtectedSessionStorage>();`
to the Program.cs and used DI to make the object available in my service class.
In my base-service class there is the following function to access my session id:

```
private string CreateOrGetSessionId()
{
  var sessionId = _sessionStorage.GetAsync<string>("MoxSessionId").Result.Value;

  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sessionId))
  {
    sessionId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    _sessionStorage.SetAsync("MoxSessionId", sessionId);
  }

  return sessionId;
}
```

**Problem**

But when I run the app nothing happens after the first row is executed (GetAsync).
On some tutorials I found hints, that there also should be a function like GetItem or so, which runs synchronusly - but none of these examples seems to work for me.

**Question**

Can anybody help me out with a working example how I could achieve my initial requirement.
I used the ProtectedSessionStorage as I saw in an example - but basicaly there is no need for protection/encryption.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say "This session id needs to be persistent as long as the browser tab is open and in use".  Does this mean over resets to the SPA such as <F5> or stepping outside the SPA?  Or within the SPA session in the Tab?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know, what's the meaning of SPA. You mean a single page application?  It's not a SPA - as I understand the term. It's a website with multiple pages as server/contact, server/login and so on. When the user access the website (any of the pages within) the first time, the session id should be generated and stored somewhere. When the user hit F5 this id should persist. But it's not nessecary to persist, if the browser/tab is closed or navigated to any other website - but it's also not forbidden, that it persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, it isn't quite as simple as it may seem because you need to deal with:

- Only being able to recover the value after the application/page/component has rendered for the first time.
- Async behaviour of components.

You also can't do it synchronously for the reasons above.

Your code block:

```cs
var sessionId = _sessionStorage.GetAsync<string>("MoxSessionId").Result.Value;
```

blocks the thread.  You're trying to shoehorn a piece of async code into a synchronous method.

Here's a Provider service to manage the value.  Note you can only get the ID by calling `GetSessionIDAsync`.  There no read property as property getters can only be sync and getting the value is async.

```cs
public class MoxSessionProvider
{
    private ProtectedSessionStorage _protectedSessionStorage;
    private Guid _sessionUid = Guid.Empty;

    public MoxSessionProvider(ProtectedSessionStorage protectedSessionStorage)
        => _protectedSessionStorage = protectedSessionStorage;

    public const string MoxSessionId = "MoxSessionId";

    public async Task<Guid> GetSessionIDAsync()
    {
        if (_sessionUid != Guid.Empty)
            return _sessionUid;

        await GetAsync();
        return _sessionUid;
    }

    private async Task GetAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await _protectedSessionStorage.GetAsync<Guid>(MoxSessionProvider.MoxSessionId);
            if (result.Success)
                _sessionUid = result.Value;

            if (!result.Success)
            {
                _sessionUid = Guid.NewGuid();
                await _protectedSessionStorage.SetAsync(MoxSessionProvider.MoxSessionId, _sessionUid);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            _sessionUid = Guid.Empty;

        }
    }
}
```

This is registered along with the `HttpContextAccessor` :

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<MoxSessionProvider>();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

We can now build a `SessionUidCascade` component to cascade the value.

```cs
@inject ProtectedSessionStorage _storage
@inject MoxSessionProvider _moxSessionState
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

<CascadingValue Name="SessionUid" Value="this.GetSessionUidTask" IsFixed=true>
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    private bool _isClientRender;
    private TaskCompletionSource<Guid?> _taskCompletionSource = new();

    public Task<Guid?> GetSessionUidTask => _taskCompletionSource.Task;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Check if we are actually rendering not server side pre-rendering
        _isClientRender = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext is not null && HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.HasStarted;

        // Yields which will ensure the component is rendered for the first time
        await Task.Yield();

        // Pre Rendering so return null
        if (!_isClientRender)
            _taskCompletionSource.SetResult(null);
        
        // Rendering so get the value
        if (_isClientRender)
        {
            var uid = await _moxSessionState.GetSessionIDAsync();
            _taskCompletionSource.SetResult(uid);
        }
    }
}
```

Add it to `App` so everyone can capture the cascade.

```cs
<SessionUidCascade>
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, theres nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
</SessionUidCascade>
```

You can consume it like this in an component - `SessionUidComponent`.

```cs
        <div class="bg-dark text-white p-2 m-2">
            <pre>Session ID: @(_sessionUid is null ? "Retrieving" : _sessionUid) </pre>
        </div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter(Name = "SessionUid")] public Task<Guid?> SessionUidTask { get; set; } = default!;

    private Guid? _sessionUid = Guid.Empty;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(SessionUidTask);
        _sessionUid = await SessionUidTask;
    }
}
```

```cs
@page "/"
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<SessionUidComponent />
```

Comment: I don't understand all the details - in special the part with the "cascade".
But at the end, as far as I can see, the ID is just avaiable on pages (components) with this solution.

I just added OnAfterRenderAsync into my PageBase and can get the session id and use it on all pages.
But basically I need it within the service - is there an other way than building a function service.SetSessionId(string sessionId) and call it from the pages?

Comment: You can't use a property because how would you populate it internally in the service?  You can't call it in the constructor: constructors are synchronous and at the time of injection `ProtectedSessionStorage` probably doesn't have access to the *HttpContext* to retrieve the value.  If you have to call a method to populate the property then where do you call it from?  And if you have to call a method then just return the value from the method.  Once it's got the value the first time it's almost as trivial as a property getter.

Comment: To access the value in the service you call - `var value = await GetSessionIDAsync();`.  It's the async non blocking equivalent of `CreateOrGetSessionId()`.

Comment: I'm sorry - but I can't get it working.
I created the MoxSessionProvider as you mentioned and provided it by DI to my pages and services.
As long as I call the method from the async methods on pages with `await GetSessionIDAsync()` it works fine.
But from services I don't have any async methods - but otherwise the `await` call is not valid.

At some point I need to connect sync and async - or at least I think so !?

I assume I'm strugling with just a tiny thing - but at the moment I'm not able to see the forest for the trees.
I'm sorry.

Comment: You need to learn async coding.  The saying in Blazor is "Async All The Way".  you can't switch from Async to Sync without causing all sorts of problems (as you are finding out).  "But from services I don't have any async methods".  You write your service methods as async code.  Can you provide an example of the service code where you you want to consume the Id?

Comment: I think I was able to handle it somehow.
I created `public async Task InitMoxClient()` in my ServiceBase where I store the connection to a private variable.
An on the page in the `OnAfterRenderAsync` I await this task if rendered for the first time

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is put this create/get logic into an async function within your `OnInitializedAsync` or `OnAfterRenderAsync` (depending on your server mode) method and set /read the item from there.

Comment: As far as I know until now, this two functions are part of the page/code behind - not of the service.
That's why this doesn't solve my problem.

I did the test this way - it works, but I asume there needs to be a prettier way then passing the value from the page to the service!?